Variable visibility in python
Maybe a stupid question but I'm new to python.
The following code throws an error:
deck = [10, 2, 5, 8, 2, 7]
deck_idx = 0

def deal():
  card = deck[deck_idx]
  deck_idx += 1
  return card

print(deal())

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(deal())   
  File "main.py", line 6, in deal
    card = deck[deck_idx] 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'deck_idx' referenced before assignment

while this doesn't:
deck = [10, 2, 5, 8, 2, 7]
deck_idx = 0

def deal():
  card = deck[0]
  return card

print(deal())


10

both deck and deck_idx are declared in the same place, so I expect them to have the same visibility.
What am I missing here?

Assigning to deck_idx turns it into a new local variable, and since you're assigning to it based on its previous value, you get an UnboundLocalError.  You probably want to use the global keyword.  (Better yet, when you deal, just pop a card off the list instead of tracking an extra piece of state...)

What do you mean by "visibility"? Child scopes can in fact read both of them, if that's what you mean, and you would see that if you changed deck[0] to deck[deck_idx]. But when you assign to deck_idx in version 1 of the function, that creates a new local that shadows the global deck_idx.

What am I missing here? In the first example you are assigning to deck_idx, and in the second one you are not.  When you assign to a variable inside of a function, it is assumed to be a local variable, even if there is already a global variable of the same name.

Thank you @JohnGordon this clarifies the situation. Coming from other languages this seems a bit weird...
I used the global keyword (thank you @Samwise) and now it works
